# Query taking long time to execute in AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, rds

I am working on some temp tables for practice.
The one query is taking too much of time around 550  sec.Db is hosted in AWS RDS with 8cpu and 16GB ram.
Below query has to be run in different DB( prod ) , first checking in test testDB

```
create table test_01 as  
 select * 
    from
        (
   select
    person
                ,age
                ,dob
                ,place
             from
     person
   where
     person is not null
                and age is not null
                and dob is not null
                and place is not null
    limit 1000
  ) ps_u
 left join
  employee em_u
  on ps_u.age = em_u.em_age
  and ps_u.place = em_u.location
 order by person
    limit 1000
```

Is there issue with query or with the resource,
CPU utilization shows 30% ram is ok not too much.
Let me know any suggestion to optimize the query.

Answer (score 1):

1. check your **left join**. it can be a reason for it. left join will return everything from your left table, if this table has lot of entry, it will slow down your query.
2. With it, you can break your query in two separate query & check execution time using different tweaking.
3. Try to return specific rows rather than *.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are limiting the result (with `limit 1000`) - do you really need `order by person`? If the result is huge - `order by` could adversely affect the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce 1 select statement / also left join bring all records from left table could take  time to process data.

```
CREATE TABLE test_01 AS
  (SELECT person,
          age,
          dob,
          place
   FROM person ps_u
   LEFT JOIN employee em_u ON ps_u.age = em_u.em_age
   AND ps_u.place = em_u.location
   ORDER BY ps_u.person
   WHERE ps_u.person IS NOT NULL
     AND ps_u.age IS NOT NULL
     AND ps_u.dob IS NOT NULL
     AND ps_u.place IS NOT NULL
   LIMIT 1000)
```

Comment: above query also taking same amount of time, all the column datatype is of text

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating index for the column

```
alter table person
add fulltext index `fulltext`

    (
     , person asc
        , age asc
        , dob asc
        , place asc
    )
    ;
```

And then the query took only 3 seconds for 1000 records